# Average rating score vs number reviews

Tags: gui-design, layout, lists, interface, ratings

I am designing a list, and under the name of each product, there is a rating based in 5 stars.

Next to it we want to display average rating in numbers (i.e., 4.3/5) and/or total number or reviews (i.e. 342 reviews).

The problem is that it seems a lot of information

Which of these is more useful, are there any studies on this subject?

Answer (score 6):

It's not a lot of information.

Amazon already do something similar.[image]

It's quite informative.

Answer (score 0):

**Displaying just 1 will make the other lose a good part of its meaning.**

For example, unless the review is very detailed, **what would be your impression of a product with 1 start (or 5) if t has just 1 review vs one that has 500 reviews?*
It's a very different situation!

If you don't display the numbers of reviews too, **you could be creating a possible false image of the product**, which is not a good thing.
On the other side, if you don't display the rating the user would have to enter the product description just to see that.

So the best option without a doubt is to **show them both**. Here examples from:

- Amazon:

  [image]
- AliExpress:

  [image]